# Determine what VM is running my Azure DevOps agent

Tags: azure-devops

I inherited an Azure DevOps gig (of course with little documentation) and now I am trying to determine what VM is running the self hosted agents.
I can't seem to find a direct (easy) way other than look at each VM (34 are here).

Is there a way to identify what VM is running the agent from the DevOps or Azure portal?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

nvm. Found it under agent pools - agents - capabilities.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

In Portal Azure Devops Click in organization Setting.
[image]

you find the option agent Pools.

[image]

Click in pool

[image]

Click in agent and find de option Capabilities.
[image]

In this windows you have the field Agent.ComputerName in windows.

this script read all pools and generate a file with all agents and computername.

```
(az pipelines pool list --query "[].{id:id,name:name}" | ConvertFrom-Json ) | ForEach-Object { 
    #write-host "pool "$_.id

    $poolid=$_.id
    $poolname=$_.name
    (az pipelines agent list --pool-id $poolid --query "[].{id:id,name:name}" | ConvertFrom-Json ) | ForEach-Object { 
            #write-host "a"$_.id
            $agent_id=$_.id
            $agent_name=$_.name
            $name_server=(az pipelines agent show --pool-id $poolid --id $agent_id --include-capabilities | ConvertFrom-Json ).systemCapabilities."Agent.ComputerName"
            $log="$poolid |$poolname | $agent_id | $agent_name | $name_server"
            write-host "$log" 
            $log >> all_agents.txt
            }

}
```